# Home/front page won't display content after a form is submitted

Tags: frontpage

I have setup a WordPress site using just pages (no posts) http://dev3.sugarvine.com/

I've created all the pages in the backend and made the 'About' page the front page. All the pages use index.php to display the page and content.

I have a newsletter submit from in the sidebar that when it gets submitted it uses an anchor link to ensure that the user always sees the response form message. All of this works fine on all pages except the About / home /front page.

Here's the problem: If i submit the form on the homepage it returns me back but does not show the homepages content. Yet on all the other pages the returning pages content will still be displayed.

Can anyone suggest a fix to my problem.

Thanks

Comment: Paste some relevant code, for all we know it's a misplaced `if...else` statement.

Comment: Hi @Soulseekah I did a few tests this morning based on if statements but nothing resolved the issue. 

However, I have been able to fix the issue by replacing the form with another form and this has fixed the issue. I’m still not clear why the old form would would work on one page and not the homepage but as I’ve already spent way too much time trying to fix the problem I’m not going to debug the old from to figure out the reasons why, I’m just happy it is now fixed!

Comment: Paste your original code, paste your fixed code as an answer, accept the answer. Don't let the question hang like this, please.